# lesshint custom rule get the filename being walked

Tags: less

I'm creating a custom linting rule in **[lesshint](https://github.com/lesshint/lesshint)**.

I want to access the filename of the file being walked.

Current code:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'customrule',
    nodeTypes: ['decl'],

    lint: function(config, node) {        
        console.log(node.root().source.input.from);        
    }
};
```

The closest I've got is `node.root().source.input.from` which seems to output the index of the file, but not its name.

`config` object seems to be a boolean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lead maintainer of `lesshint` here.

I've just pushed an update where the full file path will be included on all nodes. You can access it via the `source` property, like this:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'customrule',
    nodeTypes: ['decl'],

    lint: function(config, node) {        
        console.log(node.source.input.file)     
    }
};
```

The value of `config` will be the value you specified for it in your `.lesshintrc` file. For example:

```
{
    "customrule": {
        "enabled": true,
        "option": false
    }
}
```

Will pass that object in `config`.

Link to the newly released version: https://github.com/lesshint/lesshint/releases/tag/v4.6.2